How to get the function multivari (plotrix) running with a data import from Excel
I'm relatively new to R and wrote the below script with RStudio to create a MultiVari chart. When I want to import data from an Excel sheet as dataset I get an error message (= dataset MVData) :
Error in dat_split[[i]][fac1][!is.na(data[[var]]), ]:
! Can't subset rows with !is.na(data[[var]]).
✖ Logical subscript !is.na(data[[var]]) must be size 1 or 24, not 48.
However, when I build the data set with data.frame (= dataset RRData) the script runs without issues.

library(SixSigma)
library(dplyr)
library(plotrix)
library(readxl)

# Create data set
waarde = c(0.68, -2.09, 1.74, 1.84, -1.7, 0.24, -0.6, -0.23, -0.63, -0.3, 0.75, -0.34, 0.1, 0.32, 0.35, 0.11, 0.31, 0.19, 0.05, -0.01, -0.06, 0.3, 0.33, 0.16, 5.06, 4.18, 5.14, 4.34, 4.29, 4.06, 6.07, 3.7, 6.31, 5.45, 4.72, 5.26, 3.31, 3.47, 3.12, 3.34, 3.27, 2.78, 3.59, 3.57, 3.88, 3.54, 3.67, 3.82)
proces = c('Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'Blank', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA', 'PSA')
type = c('Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Vierkant', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat', 'Plaat')
operator = c('BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM', 'BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM', 'BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM', 'BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'BL', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM', 'JM')
run = c('R1', 'R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R2', 'R2', 'R1', 'R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R2', 'R2', 'R1', 'R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R2', 'R2', 'R1', 'R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R2', 'R2', 'R1', 'R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R2', 'R2', 'R1', 'R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R2', 'R2', 'R1', 'R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R2', 'R2', 'R1', 'R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R2', 'R2')
ID = c('1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3')
meting = c('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
RRData = data.frame(waarde,proces, type, operator, run, ID, meting)
print(RRData)

# Import data from excel sheet
MVData <- read_excel("InputMultiVari.xlsx", 
          col_types = c("numeric", "text", "text","text", "text", "text", "text"))
print(MVData)

# Multi Vari chart
multivari("waarde", "ID", "operator", "run", "type",
          data = MVData,
          fac.cex = 1.5,
          main = "Multi-Vari Chart"
)


Does somebody have a clue how I can resolve this and use the Excel file as import?
I tried to change the variable types for the different colmuns but that didn't change the outcome.
Thanks
The result from dput(MVData)
> dput(MVData)
structure(list(waarde = c(0.68, -2.09, 1.74, 1.84, -1.7, 0.24, 
-0.6, -0.23, -0.63, -0.3, 0.75, -0.34, 0.1, 0.32, 0.35, 0.11, 
0.31, 0.19, 0.05, -0.01, -0.06, 0.3, 0.33, 0.16, 5.06, 4.18, 
5.14, 4.34, 4.29, 4.06, 6.07, 3.7, 6.31, 5.45, 4.72, 5.26, 3.31, 
3.47, 3.12, 3.34, 3.27, 2.78, 3.59, 3.57, 3.88, 3.54, 3.67, 3.82
), proces = c("Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank", 
"Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank", 
"Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank", 
"Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "PSA", "PSA", "PSA", "PSA", 
"PSA", "PSA", "PSA", "PSA", "PSA", "PSA", "PSA", "PSA", "PSA", 
"PSA", "PSA", "PSA", "PSA", "PSA", "PSA", "PSA", "PSA", "PSA", 
"PSA", "PSA"), type = c("Vierkant", "Vierkant", "Vierkant", "Vierkant", 
"Vierkant", "Vierkant", "Vierkant", "Vierkant", "Vierkant", "Vierkant", 
"Vierkant", "Vierkant", "Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat", 
"Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat", 
"Vierkant", "Vierkant", "Vierkant", "Vierkant", "Vierkant", "Vierkant", 
"Vierkant", "Vierkant", "Vierkant", "Vierkant", "Vierkant", "Vierkant", 
"Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat", 
"Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat", "Plaat"), operator = c("BL", 
"BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", 
"BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", 
"JM", "BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", 
"JM", "JM", "BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "JM", "JM", "JM", 
"JM", "JM", "JM"), run = c("R1", "R1", "R1", "R2", "R2", "R2", 
"R1", "R1", "R1", "R2", "R2", "R2", "R1", "R1", "R1", "R2", "R2", 
"R2", "R1", "R1", "R1", "R2", "R2", "R2", "R1", "R1", "R1", "R2", 
"R2", "R2", "R1", "R1", "R1", "R2", "R2", "R2", "R1", "R1", "R1", 
"R2", "R2", "R2", "R1", "R1", "R1", "R2", "R2", "R2"), ID = c("1", 
"2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", 
"3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", 
"1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", 
"2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"), meting = c("1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -48L))

And the result of identical(MVData, RRData)
> identical(MVData, RRData)
[1] FALSE


Do you mean that when you call multivari with  RRData it works but with MVData it doesn’t and you believe the two data frames are identical? If so, then we need to see MVData. Please add the output from dput(MVData) to your question. The result of identical(MVData, RRData) would also be a useful initial diagnostic.

You are right, with RRData it works but with MVData it doesn’t. I added the outputs to my question.

The issue is caused by inconsistency of classes for RR- and MVData. And that's caused by classes of the object returned by read_excel() function:
readxl::read_excel(path = "~/abc.xlsx") |>
  class()
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame" 

However multivari() function expect a data frame. From help you can read:
[...]
data    a data frame, required

Back to your data:
[...]

class(RRData)
#> [1] "data.frame"
class(MVData)
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

MVData <- MVData |> 
  as.data.frame()

multivari("waarde", "ID", "operator", "run", "type",
          data = MVData,
          fac.cex = 1.5,
          main = "Multi-Vari Chart"
)


Created on 2024-10-26 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks for the explanation, I see now what went wrong. I changed the script and it works.
